# Loop in stored procedure of SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a stored procedure like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[insert_sms] 
    (@msg VARCHAR(MAX), @nodeid INT)    
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO dbo.ManAlarm ([Mobile], [Content]) 
    VALUES ((SELECT Mobile FROM NodesMobileSMS WHERE NodeID = @nodeid), @msg);
END
```

How can I write loop script that with each Mobile number in `(select Mobile from NodesMobileSMS)` will execute an insert query?

**Edit**:

```
select Mobile 
from NodesMobileSMS 
where NodeID = @nodeid
```

will return "1;2;3;4;5" (dynamic values for each select query), and I want to write a loop for each number in "1;2;3;4;5", it will insert a row into `ManAlarm`:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.ManAlarm ([Mobile], [Content]) 
VALUES (1, @msg);
INSERT INTO dbo.ManAlarm ([Mobile], [Content]) 
VALUES (2, @msg);
...
INSERT INTO dbo.ManAlarm ([Mobile], [Content]) 
VALUES (5, @msg);
```

but **NOT** insert like this:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.ManAlarm ([Mobile], [Content]) 
VALUES ('1;2;3;4;5', @msg);
```

**Edit2**:
I have wrote a function splitString and insert with query:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.ManAlarm ([Mobile], [Content]) 
SELECT *,'message' from dbo.splitString('1;2;3;4;5',';');
```

It is successfully! Thanks all!

Comment: Don't use loops in SQL, the language is prepared to work with sets of rows per operation. Loops and cursors are slow and usually a bad practice, with some exceptions. You can search for the term RBAR to find out more.

Comment: Keep in mind that, this is not a efficient approach if you planning to do insert 100000's of records.

Comment: no, the max records for insert only 20 rows

Comment: Please post your data set and your wished result set

Comment: Dear, the result of your query is 1;2;3;4;5 (only one row with these values), so you want to split those values and put in your table?

Comment: Please add the version of your SQL Server? I hope 2016 minimum :)

Comment: yes, i'm using sql server 2016 :D

Comment: if split after that also have to using loop for insert :(

Comment: Use STRING_SPLIT

Comment: Check my edited answer

Comment: sorry, with sql server 2016 it will ok with STRING_SPLIT. but on my server, it is running with sql server 2008 R2 :(((( sorry because my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write as follow:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.ManAlarm([Mobile], [Content]) 
SELECT Mobile, @msg from NodesMobileSMS where NodeID = @nodeid
```

In upper query I've simply removed the `VALUES` keyword, so you put in your `ManAlarm` table the output of `SELECT`

But if you want to write a loop you can use a `CURSOR` on `NodesMobileSMS` but is not a good choice about performance.

**EDIT (After the Kid1412 comment)**

If you want to write, in `ManAlarm`, the same rows present in `NodesMobileSMS` but with the same value you must write as follow:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.ManAlarm([Mobile], [Content]) 
SELECT 1, @msg from NodesMobileSMS where NodeID = @nodeid
```

If you want to add an arbitrary number of rows yo can put your `INSERT` in a `FOR` loop

**EDIT (After Kid1412 has said he use Sql Server 2016)**

```
INSERT INTO dbo.ManAlarm([Mobile], [Content]) 
SELECT STRING_SPLIT(Mobile, ';'), @msg from NodesMobileSMS where NodeID = @nodeid
```

Comment: if that, it will insert Mobile is an string array same that "1;2;3;4;5" but i want insert same that:
INSERT INTO dbo.ManAlarm([Mobile], [Content]) 
VALUES(1,@msg);

INSERT INTO dbo.ManAlarm([Mobile], [Content]) 
VALUES(2,@msg);

...

Comment: @Kid1412: you have put, in your question, that select as source. If you want to add the same cardinality of select result, you can re-write your query with 1 instead of Mobile value.

Comment: but the (SELECT Mobile from NodesMobileSMS) will return dynamic values, so that can not re-write query

Comment: @Kid1412: Please post your data set and your wished result set, so I can help you better